# How to make a portable Pyramid application

Tags: pyramid

I'm starting a Pyramid application on OSX which will eventually be deployed on Ubuntu. The application will need packages such as boto and pymongo. What do I need to do to make the application easy to deploy on Ubuntu?

Comment: I think ``Vagrant`` will help you

Comment: Vagrant always manages virtual machines. This guy just wants to deploy a python application. This can be accomplished with typical python distribution methods.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow any of the tutorials pyramid provides using scaffolds either on OSX and on Ubuntu. This will show you how pyramid application requirements are managed. It is abstracted by defining requirements in setup.py or requirement.txt for example.

- [SQLAlchemy + URL Dispatch Wiki Tutorial](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/wiki2/index.html)
- [ZODB + Traversal Wiki Tutorial](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/wiki/index.html)

Really, all you need to start to be productive with pyramid is here

- [Getting Started](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid/en/latest/index.html#getting-started)

After finishing your application you may distribute a source distribution/archive (*.tar.gz)

- [Distribute your application](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/wiki2/distributing.html)

Install your application on Ubuntu with `pip` and pass the path to your local source archive. You need to install your package into `development mode` either using `pip` or `setuptools`. Below you will find the `--editable` option from pip:

```
$ pip install --help

Usage:   
  pip install [options] <requirement specifier> ...
  pip install [options] -r <requirements file> ...
  pip install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
  pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
  pip install [options] <archive url/path> ...

Description:
  Install packages from:

  - PyPI (and other indexes) using requirement specifiers.
  - VCS project urls.
  - Local project directories.
  - Local or remote source archives.

  pip also supports installing from "requirements files", which provide
  an easy way to specify a whole environment to be installed.

Install Options:
  -e, --editable <path/url>   Install a project in editable mode (i.e.
                              setuptools "develop mode") from a local project
                              path or a VCS url.
```

I recommend to use `virtualenv` to isolate your work on any platform.